# Generate an error in Typescript when this is used "incorrectly

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio

I've seen a number of issues in the web project I'm working on where someone uses the "this" object accidentally.  This happens most often when someone does a copy-paste from a method inside a class into a pure function.  This almost always results in a runtime error "Cannot access XXXXXX in undefined" or something similar in the JS console.

Is there any easy way to have Typescript generate an error in this case?  I haven't found a compiler option that does it.  Do I have to install something like TSLint?

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't found a compiler option that does it.

The compiler option you are looking for is `noImplicitThis`

## More

From : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

> Raise error on this expressions with an implied any type.

Answer (score 0):

The `noImplicitThis` flag recommended by Basarat is the first step.

But what should you do when that flag causes TypeScript to error? If you insist on having your method as a standalone function, you can maintain type safety by defining `this` explicitly. Consider this example:

```
class Person {
  constructor(readonly name: string) {}

  greet() {
    console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}`);
  }
}

const person = new Person('Bob');

person.greet();
```

This works great. But what if you want `greet` to be a function on its own?

The solution: tell TypeScript that `greet` can only be called with `this` of `Person`.

```
function greet(this: Person) {
  console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}`);
}

greet.call(person)
```

The `this` parameter always comes first on the parameters list.